# Dev Studio 10.3 - connector discovery completed without finding any connectors jboss developer studio

Tags: jboss-developer-studio

I get this error when trying to look at available packages in Red Hat JBoss Central. This seems to be because of some missing files on the update site.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install devstudio 10.3?

Into your own Eclipse (from update site, from Marketplace, from zip), via rpm, or via installer jar? If into Eclipse, which package (JavaEE, Java, C/C++, etc.) and which source did you use?

Are you behind a firewall/proxy? What OS are you running? Which version of JDK are you using?

Just tried to install everything from Central from devstudio-10.3.0.GA-v20170218-1636-B94-installer-standalone.jar installation on Fedora 24 and it works for me.